# Name of horror film about train and reality shift in tunnels?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Please remind what film it was. Plot goes like this:

A passenger walks onto the train and starts his trip. He notices a boy with a plastic toy gun that emits only light and sound. Also an obese man that eats spaghetti.

After a while someones starts screaming something like THE TUNNEL IS COMING! THE TUNNEL IS COMING! All passengers start preparing for something, but main character doesn't know what to expect.

As train drives into the tunnel the reality changes. Toy gun in boys hands became a real one. Kid starts shooting everyone including obese man. We can see real blood on him.

After tunnel has ended reality is shifted back again. Gun became a toy. Obese man wakes up and notices that he spilled ketchup on his shirt, on the very place he got wounded and got blood, now it's just a ketchup.

Also nobody can't leave train on any station, unless they present "a ticket". But nobody on this train got one. Thus train continues its journey through tunnels and reality change.

Comment: I remember seeing this when I was a kid (in the 80s).  I especially remember the kid with the gun that turned real.  I am almost positive it was an episode from "Tales From the Darkside", but could have been from another anthology series.  Hopefully someone here remembers better than me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some quick digging, and found that this from Season 2, episode 19 of "Tales From the Darkside" called "The Last Car".

There's a full synopsis at http://talesfromthedarkside.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Car

Here's an excerpt with the kid's toy gun becoming real:

> Another tunnel arrives, and things start to freak out once more. It's
>   a little more serious this time, though - in addition to the flashing
>   lights and shaking, an argument over playing cards escalates into
>   murder when the kid grabs his toy gun and fills the old man with lead.
>   Stacy is terrified and the boy starts shooting at her next. She dodges
>   the bullets, which tear through her seat.
>
> The tunnel ends and everything goes back to normal. The old man's
>   alive (although still bloody) and coed returns to her bullet-riddled
>   seat, somewhat shell-shocked.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly that film.

It seems odd how my memory of this film is different from what it actually is. So many details are wrong. :D